# Clicking "sort" makes the page jump to the top

Tags: bug, new-nav

Clicking "sort" on the *new* navigation makes the page jump to the top.

> [image]

To repro:

1. Scroll a bit, but have "sort" drop down visible
2. Click it.
3. Profit! The page jumps to the top.